# Iranian Car Plate Recognition in C#

Tags: opencv, image-processing, c#-4.0, ocr

I use C# to Detect Car Plate area in image and extracted plate area as image from base image but I don't know how to extract plate number from image to string for Iranian Plate numbers?
this is Iranian plate style
[image]

for example this is my input picture

[image]

and following is my result

[image]

What I need is
۶۶
ق
۶۶۶
۱۱
from my last result in string format.

Comment: obviously you need to feed that plate image into OCR that is capable of recognizing Iranian letters. that's obvious, so what is your actual question/problem?

Comment: Tesseract is the "de facto standard" of OCR freeware.

Comment: @Piglet
I am looking for free or open source c# library that is capable to recognize Persian language

Comment: then open any websearch and search for it. asking for library recommendations is explicitly against the guidelines of this community. this is no websearch service. if any useful library exists it will be found via websearch. google knows more libraries than us...